# Where do I write the code for kafka connect sink custom partitioner?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

This may be a very simple question so I'll apologise in advance.
I am adding an s3 sink connector for a kafka topic, conf file here:

```
{
  "schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "my-s3-sink",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "errors.log.enable": "true",
  "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
  "topics": [
    "my-topic-name"
  ],
  "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "flush.size": "2000",
  "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "600000",
  "s3.bucket.name": "my-bucket-name",
  "s3.object.tagging": "true",
  "s3.region": "region",
  "s3.part.size": "5242880",
  "aws.access.key.id": "****",
  "aws.secret.access.key": "****",
  "s3.ssea.name": "AES256",
  "s3.compression.type": "gzip",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "topics.dir": "",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
  "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
  "path.format": "YYYY/MM/dd/HH",
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "timezone": "UTC"
}
```

This outputs the messages in the format `{topic_name}/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/{message}`, where I want the key to just be `YYYY/MM/DD/HH/{message}`. After some research I found that in order to remove the topic name from the key I have to write a custom partitioner that extends and overrides parts of the `TimeBasedPartitioner`. (here is an example https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/321)

My problem is that I now do not know where to write the actual code for that partitioner, where should it live? The time based partitioner seems to link to some sort of registry owned by confluent, but where would custom ones go and how would I reference that code in the conf file for the connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write the code in a separate project, compile it to a JAR, then place it on the classpath of each connect worker.

Then you can refer to it from `partitioner.class`